# Developing a RESTful Cocoa web service

Tags: cocoa, web-services

I want to develop a RESTful Web service in Cocoa. I have seen plenty of examples that have been done with .Net (Windows Communication Foundation), JAVA, Python etc. 
   However, can any one point me to some framework or Library that can be used to deveop a RESTful Web serivice?
   You can also send me an example to develop a Generic Web serice in Cocoa (not necessarily a RESTful).

Comment: Are you wanting to host the web service via a server in your app?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this sample project: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CocoaHTTPServer/Introduction/Intro.html